# Looping through the form elements and validate each field JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to create dynamic form validation for each field. Each element on the form is warped in separate div. Any required field on the form has the class 'required' set on the label element. Here is example of my form:

```js
$('.datepick').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('readonly', true).css("background-color", "#DCDCDC").datepicker({
      format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'focus',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            closeText: 'Clear',
            onClose: function(){
                var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
                
                if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            } 
     });
 });
```

```css
.required:before {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#">
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Info</legend>
       <div class="formItem">
        <label for="last_name" class="required">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frmst_lname" id="frmst_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." />
       </div>
       <div class="formItem">
        <label for="first_name" class="required">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frmst_fname" id="frmst_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters." />
       </div>
       <div class="formItem">
        <label for="dob" class="required">DOB:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frmst_dob" id="frmst_dob" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="datepick" />
       </div>
                <div class="formItem">
        <label for="sport" class="required">Sport:</label>
        <select name="frmst_sport" id="frmst_sport">
         <option value="">--Choose Sport--</option>
         <cfoutput query="getSports">
          <option value="#d_dist#">#d_sname#</option>
         </cfoutput>
        </select>
             </div>
                <div class="formItem">
           <p align="center"><input type="button" name="frmSubmit" id="frmstSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
          </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
function frmValidation(frmID){
    $('#'+frmID+' label').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('required') && $(this).next('input').val() == ''){
            console.log($(this).attr('for'));
        }
    });
}
```

I was testing if loop will catch all elements with class 'required' as well as if input fields are empty for required elements. I'm wondering if this is the best option to loop through the elements? Also I would like to set the message next or under each field. If user try to submit the form but required field is empty message should appear on the screen something like this 'This field is required.'. If anyone have any suggestions or examples please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just add the `required` attribute to the required form elements and then you don't have to write any code? Or, just write `document.querySelectorAll(".required")` to get all the elements using the `required` class instead of looping through everything and testing for the class? Most, if not all, of this code is unnecessary.

Comment: What do you mean by 'you don't  have to write any code'?

Comment: If you add the `required` attribute to a form element, the browser will do validation on that element automatically.

Comment: I have tried but browser did not catch required field...

Comment: See my answer below for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript to validate required fields. Just add the `required` attribute to the required form elements.

**You must also change your "submit" button to an actual `type="submit"` button so that it will trigger the validation.** Your current "button" is just that, a regular button that when clicked does nothing in particular.

Also, remember that any kind of client-side validation is easily bypassed by someone who wants to bypass it and, as such, you should always re-validate on the server upon form submission.

```js
$('.datepick').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('readonly', true).css("background-color", "#DCDCDC").datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'focus',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'Clear',
    onClose: function(){
      var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
      if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
        $(this).val('');
      }
    } 
 });
});

// Submit event handler
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(evt){
  console.log("This code is only reached when all fields are valid.");

  evt.preventDefault();   // Cancel the event
  evt.stopPropagation();  // Prevent event bubbling
  
  // Perform your AJAX call here
});
```

```css
.required:before {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

input[type="text"], select, .datepick {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:10em;
}

.submit {
  text-align:center;
  margin:1em;
}

label {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Info</legend>
    <div class="formItem">
      <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="frmst_lname" id="frmst_lname" required 
             maxlength="30" title="Maximum length 30 characters.">
    </div>
    <div class="formItem">
      <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="frmst_fname" id="frmst_fname" required  maxlength="30" 
             title="Maximum length 30 characters.">
    </div>
    <div class="formItem">
      <label for="dob">DOB:</label>
      <input type="text" name="frmst_dob" id="frmst_dob" required size="10" maxlength="10" 
             placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="datepick">
    </div>
    <div class="formItem">
      <label for="sport">Sport:</label>
      <select name="frmst_sport" id="frmst_sport" required>
        <option value="">--Choose Sport--</option>
        <cfoutput query="getSports">
          <option value="#d_dist#">#d_sname#</option>
        </cfoutput>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmstSubmit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tried 'required' on input fields but after I click on submit I can't see any message... Is this JQuery validation or something else?

Comment: @espresso_coffee  This is HTML validation. No JavaScript and no JQuery needed. It's native behavior that all HTML5 browsers have built into them. Did you see my comment that you must change your button to an `input type="submit"` so that the validation gets triggered? Without that, you are never submitting the form. Without that, you just have a button that does nothing. Did you try running my code snippet right here? Does that work for you?

Comment: After I changed type to submit validation works. There is another problem with changing type to submit. This button is linked to Ajax function. After I click on submit my form was submitted. How I can prevent this?

Comment: @espresso_coffee That is a different question, but the answer is to set up a `submit` event handler on the `form` and in it cancel the submit event. I'll update the answer with that code.

Comment: Can you please provide an example that would solve this problem?

Comment: @espresso_coffee I just updated the answer (as I said I would in the comment above). Please understand that this is a separate question from your original.